# Connecting a dimension to a URL - Tableau

Tags: hyperlink, tableau-api

I've built a dashboard in Tableau (9.1), and in it I have a dimension of "Landing Page" with a URL (another field).
I want that when the user uses the dashboard in the web interface and clicks on a specific landing page (Let's say - I have a bar graph that shows number of view for each LP - in this case, "pressing on a landing page" means pressing on the bar that represents that LP), that a new tab will open with that URL.

I've tried Dashboard Actions - but it only worked in the Tableau Desktop (when I pressed on it - in the tooltip there was a hyperlink to the LP). When I tried it in the web interface, It addresses me to a partial tableau-server URL, back-slash, and the URL for the LP. Also, after pressing 2-3 bars, the view gets messed up and an error shows.

So my question is - has anyone tried using the URL actions?
Or maybe you have a better way to make the connection between the LP dimension and it's URL (maybe pressing directly on the LP in the dimension column)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried looking into articles that reference Table of Contents using Tableau?

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-table-contents-navigate-other-dashboards